# How to create an updatable list of tuples in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm writing a script in Python 3, where I go through a file, and collect information about the duration of various tasks. I need to maintain a list of summations of these durations (in the form of datetime.timedelta objects), split by date and which task was done. Each task is identified by an ID string.

This means that while going through the file I build a list of records, where each record consist of a date, an ID string and a duration. When adding a new record I first check if the date and ID string combination is already present in the list. If it is I add the new duration to the current duration in the list. If the date and ID string combination doesn't exist, I append the record to the list.

I don't know in advance how many different combinations of date and ID string there is, so I can't pre-allocate them.

At the end I would like to be able to sort the list on date and ID string before printing it to standard out.

I tried doing it in a list of tuples, but tuples are immutable, so I can't add a new duration to an existing duration I found.

If pressed I could create a new ID string by concatenating a string representation of the date and the ID string. But I would really prefer to keep those two values separate.

Is this possible? And if so: How?

Comment: Use a dict? or a NamedTuple?

Comment: ```tuples are immutable``` I think you said it yourself. If you insist on using tuples, I think you need to create new tuples.

Comment: Why don't you use a list of lists ? But the proper way would be creating classes and instanciate objects.

Comment: @dfundako I didn't know it was possible to use a tuple as the key in the dict. I just saw Jonah Bishop's answer about it. I have no idea what a NamedTuple is. I will have to google that. Thank you.

Comment: @corentin-limier A list of lists? It seems clunky to me, but that may just be because I'm still getting used to Python. You're probably correct about taking the class/instance road.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't use a list in this case, but rather a dict. Here's a simple example:

```
data = {}

with open("myfile.txt") as file:
    for line in file:
        # Parse the line for the following:
        # tid: The task ID we read
        # date: The date we read
        # duration: The duration we read

        # Once the data has been parsed out, store it:
        data.setdefault((date, tid), 0)
        data[(date, tid)] += duration
```

After parsing the file you can get the keys to the dict (`data.keys()`), sort them, and print out the results.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know you could use a tuple as key in a dictionary. I will try that approach. Maybe I should create a date/ID-class and uses instances of that as the key. Do you know if that will work? Or if there are any pitfalls I should be aware of if I do that?

Comment: BTW is there a built-in function to sort a dictionary based on the data in the key-tuple?

Comment: Never mind. I figured it out by creating a class and overloading the comparison functions.

Comment: Creating a new class just to sort is overkill. The built-in sort functions will operate on tuples just fine. You can use a lambda expression to that pretty easily: `sorted_keys = sorted(data.keys(), key=lambda x: (x[1], x[0]))` should do it, sorting on element 1 first, then on element 0 (though I haven't tested it). You can reverse the elements if desired, or just sort on one of them.

Comment: Thanks. I'll take a look at that. I'm still learning Python, so I don't mind a bit of extra work, as long as I learn from it. But that lambda expression looks like something I definitely need to take a closer look at.